# Kotlin - checking Instant in range compared to using start >= Instant && Instant <= end

Tags: java, performance, kotlin, resources, difference

For example, you want to check in Kotlin if an Instant is in the range of start and end of other two Instants you can simply do the following:

```
import java.time.Instant
 
val start = Instant.parse("2000-10-23T00:00:00Z");
val end = Instant.parse("2020-10-23T23:59:59Z");
 
 
val toTest = Instant.parse("2010-10-24T00:00:00Z");
 
if(toTest in start..end) println("Yes") else println("No")
```

which is in my opinion pretty simple to understand

And you could also write in the standard way the following to check the same:

```
import java.time.Instant
 
val start = Instant.parse("2000-10-23T00:00:00Z");
val end = Instant.parse("2020-10-23T23:59:59Z");
 
val toTest = Instant.parse("2020-10-24T00:00:00Z");
 
val result = start <= toTest && toTest <= end
if(result) println("Yes") else println("No")
```

My question is now is there a difference in consumed resources or in additional overhead with the range solution.

Is it better for some reason to use the standard way for checking e.g. Instants within a range?

Comment: This sounds like micro-optimisation to me...

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). It's written in a C# context, but most of it still applies here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a difference in consumed resources or in additional overhead with the range solution?

The range solution actually [creates a `ClosedRange<Instant>` object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html#range), because of the `..` operator. Then `in` does exactly the same thing as the second code snippet - `start <= toTest && toTest <= end`.

So the ranges solution does do something *extra*, but in almost all the cases, this little bit of extra work won't be the main thing that slows your application down. It's not going to matter much.

> Is it better for some reason to use the standard way for checking

Yes because it is more concise and readable. It more clearly shows your intent by saying "if this instant is ***in*** this ***range***" rather than "if this instant is less than this instant and greater than that instant".

Comment: As I understood you. It is better to use the Range approach in Kotlin because is more concise/readable because the intent is more obvious and this implementation detail is abstracted behind the closed range and the minimal overhead can be neglected